# change color of flash component?

Tags: flash, actionscript, colors, components

Sorry if this question is kind of newbie I'm really new with flash but I'm using this dice on my site http://www.flashvalley.com/fv_components/dice/ and I managed to chage the color but I was wondering if it was possible to change the dots color to white as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target the movieclips/sprites and do a color transform on them

Lets say you have called each of the movieclips you want to transform "dot_mc"

```
var c:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform(); // instantiate a color transform
c.color = 0xFFFFFF; // set the color of the transform to white
dot_mc.transform.colorTransform = c; //Apply the color transform
```

So if you had many of these dots you would put them in an array and loop through the array and apply whatever color to these dots

```
var arr:Array = new Array();
arr.push(dot1_mc);
arr.push(dot2_mc);
arr.push(dot3_mc);
//
var c:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
c.color = 0xFFFFFF;  
//
for (var i:int=0; i<arr.length;i++){ 
    var mc:MovieClip = arr[i];
    mc.transform.colorTransform = c;
}
```

You could put the above in a function and call it whenever you want, passing whichever color to it and transforming the dots when necessary.

```
function changeDotColor($color_num:Number):void {
    ...
    var c:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    c.color = $color_num;
    ...
}
```

You know or pass an array of movieclips to it with the associated color. and change other MovieClips/Sprites rather than the dot movieclip.

i.e

```
function changeDotColor($color_num:Number,$mc_arr:Array):void{
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried your code but now I'm getting an error saying that the class ColorTransform couldn't be loaded, do I need to import something beforehand?

Comment: Yes you do try this at the top of your code "import flash.geom.ColorTransform;"